# Keycloak on Ubuntu

Tags: java, jdk, jvm

I have Java version 8 installed on my Ubuntu. I just installed Keycloak version 21, and when I tried to run this script from bin directory `./kc.sh start-dev` I got the following error:

```
Unrecognized option: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score -1):

Keycloak 21 is officially tested and supported with Java 11. OpenJDK 11 is a long term support version. OpenJDK 11 can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with the following command.

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

While not officially supported, some users have reported successful installations of Keycloak 21 with Java 17, however there's a possibility of encountering compatibility issues.